# When I launch an activity from main, onCreate() of main is called, and when the launched activity is finished onDestroy() is called

Tags: android

This is how I'm launching my activity:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Quotr.this, AddQuote.class);
startActivityForResult(intent, ADD_QUOTE_REQUEST);
```

And that activity finishes with a call to `finish()`

But I've been having issues with my `onCreate()` and `onDestroy()` methods being in the main activity (defined in Quotr.class) being called when I don't want them to. I added calls to Log.v() in both of those methods to see what was being called and when, and oddly, when the activity is launched, onCreate() of the main activity is called, and when the new activity is finished, the main activity's onDestroy() method is called.

This is causing a ton of issues, and I don't even know how to work around it at this point, because all my cleanup in main activity's onDestroy (which I only expect to be run when the activity is ACTUALLY recreated, not every time this new activity is launched) is being called while the activity is still in use.

Oddly enough, this only happens with this particular activity. As far as I know, I'm calling and finishing all my other activity intents in the exact same way, but they don't mess with the main activity's life cycle like this AddQuote.class one does.

I'm really at a loss for what else I can check at this point. I've checked for anything wrong in the manifest, I've checked I understand activity lifecycles, but this really makes no sense.

Answer (score 0):

Oh my god, so I'm a huge idiot.

I'm working on an app that's been slowly built up over the course of a year and a half, and it was my first ever attempt at an app. For some reason, for the first new activity I made in the app (the one I was having an issue with), I was extending the main activity instead of AppCompat activity. So my calls to super.onCreate() and super.onDestroy() were calling back to the main activity, because THAT'S the super class.

I'll leave this up anyway in the off chance someone makes this mistake as well. Hopefully it helps someone.